# Pandas DataFrame SUMIF based on cells content

Tags: python-2.7

I would need to create a sort of SUMIF function based on the content of a specific column in the dataframe itself.

In detail, I would need in each row (row N) the function to return the sum of column 'B' for all the rows that have in column 'A' the same string of that specific row (row N).

thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well I could not understand fully your task, but if I follow [definition of SUMIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b) from excel it is going to be something like this

```
cond = lambda x: x if (x > 5) else 0
a = pd.Series(1,2,3,10)
a.map(cond).sum()
```